# How to calculate time difference by group using pandas?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, difference, timedelta

### Problem

I want to calculate `diff` by group. And I don’t know how to sort the `time` column so that each group results are sorted and positive.

The original data :

```
In [37]: df 
Out[37]:
  id                time
0  A 2016-11-25 16:32:17
1  A 2016-11-25 16:36:04
2  A 2016-11-25 16:35:29
3  B 2016-11-25 16:35:24
4  B 2016-11-25 16:35:46
```

The result I want

```
Out[40]:
   id   time
0  A   00:35
1  A   03:12
2  B   00:22
```

notice: the type of time col is timedelta64[ns]

### Trying

```
In [38]: df['time'].diff(1)
Out[38]:
0                 NaT
1            00:03:47
2   -1 days +23:59:25
3   -1 days +23:59:55
4            00:00:22
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Don't get desired result.

### Hope

Not only solve the problem but the code can run fast because there are 50 million rows.

Comment: You need to sort the data first `df = df.sort_values(['id','time'])`, then you can do `df.groupby('id')['time'].diff()`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregating [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
df['diff'] = df.sort_values(['id','time']).groupby('id')['time'].diff()
print (df)
  id                time     diff
0  A 2016-11-25 16:32:17      NaT
1  A 2016-11-25 16:36:04 00:00:35
2  A 2016-11-25 16:35:29 00:03:12
3  B 2016-11-25 16:35:24      NaT
4  B 2016-11-25 16:35:46 00:00:22
```

If need remove rows with `NaT` in column `diff` use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['diff'])
print (df)
  id                time     diff
2  A 2016-11-25 16:35:29 00:03:12
1  A 2016-11-25 16:36:04 00:00:35
4  B 2016-11-25 16:35:46 00:00:22
```

You can also overwrite column:

```
df.time = df.sort_values(['id','time']).groupby('id')['time'].diff()
print (df)
  id     time
0  A      NaT
1  A 00:00:35
2  A 00:03:12
3  B      NaT
4  B 00:00:22
```

---

```
df.time = df.sort_values(['id','time']).groupby('id')['time'].diff()
df = df.dropna(subset=['time'])
print (df)
  id     time
1  A 00:00:35
2  A 00:03:12
4  B 00:00:22
```

Comment: thanks for this trick. but If i needed something in only seconds? your answer will return something like `0 days 02:20:25`

Comment: i used and it worked... thanks Jezrael ... `df.time = df.sort_values(['id','time']).groupby('id')['time'].diff().dt.total_seconds()`