# Difference between first row and current row, by group

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data set like this:

```
state,date,events_per_day
AM,2020-03-01,100
AM,2020-03-02,120
AM,2020-03-15,200
BA,2020-03-16,80
BA,2020-03-20,100
BA,2020-03-29,150
RS,2020-04-01,80
RS,2020-04-05,100
RS,2020-04-11,160
```

Now I need to compute the difference between the date in the first row of each group and the date in the current row.
i.e. the first row of each group:

- for group "AM" the first date is 2020-03-01;
- for group "BA" the first date is 2020-03-16;
- for group "RS" it is 2020-04-01.

In the end, the result I want is:

```
state,date,events_per_day,days_after_first_event
AM,2020-03-01,100,0
AM,2020-03-02,120,1    <--- 2020-03-02 - 2020-03-01
AM,2020-03-15,200,14   <--- 2020-03-14 - 2020-03-01
BA,2020-03-16,80,0     
BA,2020-03-20,100,4    <--- 2020-03-20 - 2020-03-16
BA,2020-03-29,150,13   <--- 2020-03-29 - 2020-03-16
RS,2020-04-01,80,0
RS,2020-04-05,100,4    <--- 2020-04-05 - 2020-04-01
RS,2020-04-11,160,10   <--- 2020-04-11 - 2020-04-01
```

I found [How to calculate time difference by group using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804265/how-to-calculate-time-difference-by-group-using-pandas) and it is **almost** to what I want. However, diff() returns the difference between consecutive lines, and I need the difference between the current line and the first line.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepossessing:

```
# convert to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# extract the first dates by states:
first_dates = df.groupby('state')['date'].first()  #.min() works as well
```

Option 1: Index alignment

```
# set_index before substraction allows index alignment
df['days_since_first'] = (df.set_index('state')['date'] - first_dates).values
```

Option 2: `map`:

```
df['days_since_first'] = df['date'] - df['state'].map(first_dates)
```

Output:

```
  state       date  events_per_day days_since_first
0    AM 2020-03-01             100           0 days
1    AM 2020-03-02             120           1 days
2    AM 2020-03-15             200          14 days
3    BA 2020-03-16              80           0 days
4    BA 2020-03-20             100           4 days
5    BA 2020-03-29             150          13 days
6    RS 2020-04-01              80           0 days
7    RS 2020-04-05             100           4 days
8    RS 2020-04-11             160          10 days
```

Answer (score 6):

Option 3: [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation)

```
df['days_since_first'] = df['date'] - df.groupby('state')['date'].transform('first')
```

output

```
  state        date  events_per_day days_since_first
0    AM  2020-03-01             100           0 days
1    AM  2020-03-02             120           1 days
2    AM  2020-03-15             200          14 days
3    BA  2020-03-16              80           0 days
4    BA  2020-03-20             100           4 days
5    BA  2020-03-29             150          13 days
6    RS  2020-04-01              80           0 days
7    RS  2020-04-05             100           4 days
8    RS  2020-04-11             160          10 days
```

Comment: To avoid sorting, you can change trasform("first") to transform("min")