# Timestamp difference within same group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe with timestamps and different groups. i want to take timestamp difference within same same. Similar to this question ([How to calculate time difference by group using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804265/how-to-calculate-time-difference-by-group-using-pandas)). I have done this before and it is working fine. But this time for some reason the difference is not working properly. I converted the 'group' column to string and tried many other preprocessing but it is not fruitful. What do you think is the problem this time?

[image]

I added the snippet of dataframe to show the problem I'm facing.
The code I have tried so far

```
df_2["Group"] = df_2["Group"].astype(str)
df_2 = df_2.sort_values(['Group', 'timestamp'], ascending=[False, True])
df_2["diff"] = df_2.groupby('Group')['timestamp'].diff()
```

Where do you think is the problem?

Comment: Could you please share the error output as well?

Comment: there is no error. The difference is not as required. For ex: 1st row of group G993 should be blank because there is nothing to take difference from. Except first rows of every group, I should get a difference too

Comment: Try setting df_2.loc[:,"timestamp"]=pd.to_datetime(df_2.loc[:,"timestamp"]) and recheck the code.

Comment: what is the purpose? can u pls explain

Comment: it is already in datetime

Comment: Can you edit your question and include `df_2.info()`?

Comment: df_2 has timestamp and group..

Comment: similar to the link in the question

Comment: Could you share a sample of your df?